# Static member placement delete signature?

Tags: c++

I have a project that tightly controls what and how can allocate memory. I have a base class for things that may be allocated on a heap, with static overloads for `operator new` and `operator delete` and their array variants. These work perfectly without any warnings at all.

There's an ultimate base class for everything that allows placement new only:

```
class Object
{
public:
    static void* operator new(size_t, void*);
    static void* operator new[](size_t, void*);
    static void operator delete(void*, void*);
    static void operator delete[](void*, void*);
};
```

The implementations are trivial and in the corresponding .cpp file. `operator new`s return the pointer, `operator delete`s don't do anything.

When I compile this under VS2015, using `new (ptr) DerivedFromObject()` generates the following warning. Exception handling is set to `/EHa`.

`warning C4291: 'void *Object::operator new(std::size_t,void *)': no matching operator delete found; memory will not be freed if initialization throws an exception`

I've tried messing around with the signatures: adding `noexcept`, adding `size_t` to `operator delete` but nothing seems to work. What's the correct form of static member placement `operator delete`?

Comment: It's supposed to be as you defined it http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Comment: I must also point out, that I cannot reproduce your error http://rextester.com/OHB53375

Comment: It does work for me if I try to place an Object, it's only derived classes that cause warnings. The warnings do refer to Object's operator new though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to declare `operator delete`s in every derived class to get rid of the warning.

Comment: [No you don't](http://rextester.com/edit/OHB53375). Just be sure to inherit publicly.

Comment: I did inherit publicly. This would not be the first compiler bug that I have hit in this project though, for instance doing `ptr->~DerivedFromObject()` in debug builds generates a reference to non-placement `operator delete` in unreachable code that is optimized away in release.

Comment: `ptr->~DerivedFromObject()` isn't generating a reference to operator delete at all. It's just a direct destructor call. I don't mean to sound discouraging, but your project may just be suffering from instances of undefined behavior that the compiler is desperately trying to warn you about.

Comment: It definitely did because I got a linker error that went away when I commented out that line :) I also had a look at dumpbin /disasm and my destructor call was in fact calling some thunk that called the real destructor, did some convoluted checks, and then called global operator delete in a case that couldn't happen. /O2 realized this, eliminated that part, and inlined the thunk, effectively making it a direct destructor call.

Comment: I'm not calling it anywhere. It gets called, as standard, if/when my constructor throws an exception.

Why `ptr->~ClassName()` calls non-placement `operator delete` is beyond me though, but since it's debug only I'm voting for compiler bug.

Comment: I had to re-read your previous comment. Misunderstood what was happening. If the compiler is inserting a call to the standard operator delete, I suspect something fishy is going on in the definition of your objects/placement new operators.

Comment: It's this, and a derived base that is a template and comes with its own non-placement operator new/delete implementations (that do work). However, in this case I am NOT using the template and instead deriving from Object directly because I only want placement new for that particular type.